# Directions of decrease for a convex functions

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a convex function and 
$$ f(x+\Delta x, y) < f(x,y), ~~~ f (x, y + \Delta y) < f(x,y)$$ Does this imply
$$ f(x+\Delta x, y + \Delta y) < f(x,y)$$?

I am guessing the answer is no but I'm failing to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: When you write $f(x+\Delta x, y) < f(x,y)$, do you mean that for all $(x,y)$ or just for some particular $(x,y)$?

Comment: Just for particular $x,y, \Delta x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: $f(x,y) = (x+y)(x+y-3)$, $(x,y) = (0,0)$, $\Delta x = 2$,$\Delta y = 2$

Comment: Thank you (for some reason, I cannot upvote your answer). Can you provide some intuition? How did you come up with this answer?

Comment: It's really a one-dimensional situation, but you wanted two-dimensional.  Convex functions can go down and then up.